# Indexing Range with Groupby in Pandas

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have the following Multiindex dataframe, named data:

```
Multiindex                   | Val
-----------------------------------
'A'    | 'xxx'  | 2016-10-24 | 1
                | 2016-10-25 | 2
                | 2016-10-26 | 0.5
                | 2016-10-26 | 0.5
-----------------------------------
'B'    | 'xxx'  | 2016-10-24 | 0
                | 2016-10-25 | -2
                | 2016-10-26 | -4
                | 2016-10-26 | 20
                | 2016-10-27 | 3
                | 2016-10-28 | 5
```

I want to reserve the last 20% of data from each group in level 0 of the multiindex (so the last 20% of 'A' and 'B'). I know how to get the number of elements I need for each index at level 0:

```
numElem = (data.groupby(level=0).size()*0.2).astype(np.int)
```

But I'm not sure how to go about extracting that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby().transform` with `cumcount` and `size`:

```
groups = data.groupby(level=0)
sizes = groups['Val'].transform('size')
rows = groups['Val'].cumcount()

data[rows >= 0.8 * sizes]
```